# RestAPI logging practice issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I have this issue while working on logging application events.
Below is the requirement.

- Log basic application events that are being taken place, method calls, their parameters, returns, process timings, etc..
- But only log file must contain 3 log lines for each request.

  - First line: to log request details, when a request comes in.
  - Second line: to log all application events (this was the problem)
  - Third line: to log request destroying event, when a request completes it lifecycle.

Those three requests are identified by a transaction ID created when a request is hit, this ID puts to `MDC` of `slf4j`.

Now I was told to use a `StringBuilder` to append logging details, which is supposed to initialized in a controller method, pass reference of it to every method getting called, log content of `StringBuilder` in `finally` block of controller method.

This implementation makes the entire code base ugly.
So I tried to use a `ThreadLocal` var with a `StringBuilder` to store logging details and clean it up when request is destroyed to avoid memory leaks. Instead of that I tried to use an implementation like below (pseudo).

*initialize `ThreadLocal` with an init value.*

```
public static ThreadLocal<StringBuilder> log = new ThreadLocal<StringBuilder>() {
    @Override protected StringBuilder initialValue() {
        return new StringBuilder("|Internal");
    }
};
```

*append details to this `ThreadLocal`ed `StringBuilder`*

```
SomeClass.log.get().append("|").append(whatever);
```

After all processing, in finally block of controller method will write content of this to log file as second line of log, then clean it up.
However my teammates are very doubtful about this.

- Could you please let me know is there anything wrong with the implementation in this case (is this a good approach)?
- is there any concerns such as memory leaks?

Any comment on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is AOP not a good candidate for your problem?

Comment: This sounds like question that is probably more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly address your question

Technically I see two issues with this approach:

1. Cleaning up the thread local is required in **all** controller methods. Its enough that someone somewhere will forget to put this finally block, in some controller - the things will start breaking.
   The memory leak also can come if the StringBuilder won't be cleaned up. So the data will get accumulated more and more for all thread that pass through the "leaking" controller.
2. If for some reason the BL spawns / gets executed in another thread, the code will break.

Now as for for the feature itself. I see two possible justifications for such a requirement:

- Audit
- Metering

If we're talking about the metering, given the fact that you're using spring boot already, you can implement a much more advanced metering system with Dropwizard metrics (spring boot 1.x) or Micrometer (spring boot 2.x with an available back-port to 1.5.x)

If we're talking about auditing, then the coupling to logging with a support of cleaning things up in all the controllers can be fragile as I've stated above.

One last thing I would like to pay your attention to, is this "3 lines" requirement. In general its not that easy to examine 3 messages together, usually people work with 1 line of log (search for, count, grep, whatever) and not with 3 lines at once. I'm raising this concern, since maybe it can point that its also possible to separate requirement of request logging and auditing the application business events. In this case maybe requests can be logged with one technique (filters, tomcat valves, there are many things) and auditing itself can be done with some other technique, or even technology.

If you have to use the existing solution, one interesting approach might be refactoring the logging to some AOP aspect / filter or some other well-known point, so that all controllers won't have to deal with the code that you've described

Comment: great reply, thanks, i was looking for a viable option instead of passing `StringBuilder` all around the code, i'll try mentioned options.